# Listview react-native issue rendering all rows

Tags: react-native, react-native-listview

I have a list view in my app which fetches data from api makes an array out of it and creates a datasource for it and then renders all the rows, now the dataset is not all that big and also but the list view fails to render some of the rows even the log for listview renderRow shows that only part of the dataSource is being rendered but if I remove the content container style from the listview on hot reloading it renders all the rows and on reloading it again is back to rendering only partial rows. Also the images are not being displayed in the view.[image: The images are not being rendered]

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Might help.

```
<ListView
...
removeClippedSubviews={false}
...

>
```